# Send message including button

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using Discord.js v13.2. I need to send a message once ready. I am able to send a text message, but the button does not appear, so I guess I am not sending the parameter correctly.

```
client.once("ready", async () => {
  const button = new MessageButton()
    .setLabel("Go To Site")
    .setStyle("blue")
    .setCustomId("btn-go-to-site");

  const helpChannel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID);
  helpChannel.send('Welcome to Site', button);
});
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: @MrMythical I am using: "discord.js": "^13.2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js v13 now only accepts 1 parameter in message [sending](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), [editing](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) and [replying](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply). You must send the message with the `content` and `components` parameters.

```js
helpChannel.send({
  content: "Welcome to Site",
  components: [
    new MessageActionRow().addComponents([button])
  ]
})
```

This must also be done with embeds, files, stickers and other [message options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions)

Comment: Alternatively, wouldn't it be possible create a MessageActionRow and add the Button component there? You could just use that and just send `.send({ content: `content`, components: [<MessageActionRow>]`

Comment: Adding it within the message send options is also fine

Comment: @MrMythical if you can check this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746918/discord-js-deploy-commands