# Discord JS: Deploy Commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js v13. I have successfully created a bot with scopes bot and application.commands and successfully add it to a channel on my server. Now I am following the [tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#guild-commands) for registering slash commands. I created a file deploy-commands.js with the following content:

```js
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
    const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
    const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
    const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
    
    const commands = [
        new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('Replies with pong!'),
        new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('server').setDescription('Replies with server info!'),
        new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('user').setDescription('Replies with user info!'),
    ]
        .map(command => command.toJSON());
    
    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);
    
    rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
        .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
        .catch(console.error);
```

Then I run command node deploy-commands.js and I get error:

```js
    DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access
        at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/evalenzuela/apps/discord-aurasix/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.js:198:23)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/evalenzuela/apps/discord-aurasix/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.js:99:20) {
      rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
      code: 50001,
      status: 403,
      method: 'put',
      url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/901217590259617813/guilds/901235476399280138/commands'
}
```

I have reviewed a lot of info on the internet but could not find the solution. I have triple checked the clientId, guildId and application token.

Comment: Try re-adding the bot to your Guild and making sure it has the application.commands scope there. Also make sure it has that scope in all guilds it is in, otherwise you'll get the same error.

Comment: @PedroFracassi Thanks for your comment, I have created a new application and bot, and same result, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Pedro's comment,
From [Trying to register commands: DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886388/trying-to-register-commands-discordapierror50001-missing-access):
"Have you made sure that the 'applications.commands' scope is checked in the scopes section of the OAuth2 settings for your bot in the discord developer portal?"

You mention you remade the application and bot but did not verify you correctly set the application.commands scope permission. This is likely your issue.

Comment: yes I double checked that too